# How can I label undefined spans of text in comments with Doccano?

Tags: annotations, sequence, labeling, doccano

I'm using Doccano for sequence labeling and I want to annotate spans (of an undefined length) of text in comments. The comments are saved in an xlsx/csv file. I can't upload a csv file for sequence labeling, but I need the structure. Also Doccano seems to be inserting line breaks (randomly?) and I can't use one label spanning over a line break.
How can I annotate spans of comments (of an undefined length) using Doccano? Or is there a good alternative (Windows machine, no linux, no java)?